Why doesn't $\gamma = \frac{5}{3}$ for all adiabatic processes
For monoatomic, ideal gases, $PV^{\frac{5}{3}}$ is constant. I have been told that this does not hold for diatomic, or other non-monoatomic gases. However, I derived the relationship using only the ideal gas law and the assumption that $Q=0$.
Since $Q = \Delta U+W$,
$$dU = -W$$
$$dU=-PdV$$
$$\frac{dU}{dV}=-P$$
The internal energy of an ideal gas is $\frac{3}{2} nRT = \frac{3}{2} PV$:
$$\frac{3}{2} \frac{d(PV)}{dV}=-P$$
By product rule:
$$\frac{3}{2}(\frac{dP}{dV}V+P)=-P$$
$$\frac{dP}{dV}V= -\frac{5}{3} P$$
This is a seperable differential equation which we can easily solve to get $PV^{5/3} = const$.
Nowhere did I assume that the gas was monotomic. I suspect the error might lie in the step setting $U=\frac{3}{2} PV$, but I'm not sure if this is the case and, if so, why.

There are other ways a molecule can hake up energy other than by translation - Equipartition of energy

The monoatomic gas assumption is implicit when you used $U=\frac{3}{2}k_B T$

Thank you, I was not previously aware of the derivation of the formula but this makes sense. I will accept the answer once the cooldown is complete.

The expression for molar internal energy is not always $U = 3RT/2$. That is only true for monatomic gases. The general expression is, by the equipartition theorem,
$$\frac{N}{2}RT$$
where $N$ is the number of degrees of freedom. This leads to the correct formula $\gamma = (N+2)/N$.
